# saving matplotlib image to S3 bucket from EC2 instance

Tags: matplotlib, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I am trying to save matplotlib to my S3 bucket on AWS.
I use the `savefig()` function like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure()
plt.plot(some figure)
f.savefig("s3://bucketpath/foo.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

But I get the `path not found error`.
If I don't specify the path, it seems to work fine, but I don't know where it is saved.

I am running my code (in pyspark) using sagemaker jupyterlab and therefore running on one of the EC2 instances.
Is there a way to specify the path to save the pdf to like how one would use the `write()` function when saving dataframes to an S3 bucket?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485660/python-uploading-a-plot-from-memory-to-s3-using-matplotlib-and-boto) post on this site, but it is for uploading from your local client to S3 on the cloud using boto.
Is there a way to save it directly to S3 without using aws access keys etc?

Comment: Is this actually not possible in EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar problem on a Jupyter Notebook running on AWS EMR, while trying to save another binary file format (png) to S3. I solved the issue by interfacing with S3 using the `s3fs` library.

Using your example, it should look something like this:

```
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import s3fs

plt.plot(some figure)

img_data = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(img_data, format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
img_data.seek(0)

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)  # Uses default credentials
with s3.open('s3://bucketpath/foo.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img_data.getbuffer())
```

I've noticed you were working on Sagemaker JupyterLab, but looking at `s3fs` docs, I believe it would work as well.

My solution was based on [the answer you mentioned in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40925995/5910757) and [s3fs documentation](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)