# Saving a pdf image to an s3 bucket in amazon braket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724324/saving-matplotlib-image-to-s3-bucket-from-ec2-instance). I have a jupyter notebook in which I execute amazon braket.

How do I save the image in S3 specifying the path? I cannot use the answer linked above because, at least for me, `import s3fs` yields `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 's3fs'`

Comment: you can installing using pip, try pip install s3fs or pip3 install s3fs

Comment: Was this notebook launched through SageMaker or is it native EC2?

Comment: Yup, sagemaker. I don't think pip3 will be of use here.